# data.table create dynamic column name with vector recycling

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want to replicate in `data.table` the behaviour of `dplyr` for expanding rows through `group_by` and `reframe`. I am able to do it by setting column names myself, but I don't know how to do it if I am setting dynamic column names (i.e., based on external vectors). Example below:

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

iris <- as.data.table(iris)

# Dplyr
varname <- c("new_var")
var_levels <- c("level1", "level2")
iris %>% 
  group_by(pick(everything())) %>% 
  reframe({{varname}} := var_levels) 
#> # A tibble: 298 × 6
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new_var
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <chr>  
#>  1          4.3         3            1.1         0.1 setosa  level1 
#>  2          4.3         3            1.1         0.1 setosa  level2 
#>  3          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa  level1 
#>  4          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa  level2 
#>  5          4.4         3            1.3         0.2 setosa  level1 
#>  6          4.4         3            1.3         0.2 setosa  level2 
#>  7          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  level1 
#>  8          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  level2 
#>  9          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3 setosa  level1 
#> 10          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3 setosa  level2 
#> # ℹ 288 more rows


# Data.table:
iris[, .(new_var = var_levels) , keyby = names(iris)]
#>      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species new_var
#>   1:          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1    setosa  level1
#>   2:          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1    setosa  level2
#>   3:          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2    setosa  level1
#>   4:          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2    setosa  level2
#>   5:          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2    setosa  level1
#>  ---                                                                    
#> 294:          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica  level2
#> 295:          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica  level1
#> 296:          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica  level2
#> 297:          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica  level1
#> 298:          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica  level2


# Dynamic data.table?
iris[, (varname) := var_levels, keyby= names(iris)] 
#> Error in `[.data.table`(iris, , `:=`((varname), var_levels), keyby = names(iris)): Supplied 2 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 1 in column 'new_var'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The only solution I can think of is:

```r
iris[, .(varname = var_levels) , keyby = names(iris)]
iris <- iris %>% rename({{varname}} := varname)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `data.table` parlance, since you're grouping by all pre-existing columns, we don't want `:=`-assignment, we want to return a single column and have `data.table` preserve the grouped columns. You started down the right path with your `.(varname = var_levels)` step, we just need a way to name the column dynamically. We can do that using `setNames` on `list(var_levels)`.

```r
irisDT <- as.data.table(iris)
out <- irisDT[, setNames(list(var_levels), varname), keyby = names(irisDT)]
irisDT %>% 
  group_by(pick(everything())) %>% 
  reframe({{varname}} := var_levels) %>%
  all.equal(out, check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!!